# C# Data Annotations not showing correct Display Name

Tags: c#, razor, model, blazor, data-annotations

Here is a snippet from my Model class

```
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Birth Day")]
    public DateTime customerBirthDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Today;
```

Here is a snippet from my razor file

```
                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
                    <span class="label-input100">Date of Birth</span>
                    <InputDate class="input100" id="birthday" name="birthday" @bind-Value="CurrentCustomerSubmission.customerBirthDate" />
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Model.customerBirthDate)" />
                </div>
```

When i delete the date from the InputDate field, I am expecting it to say

"The Birth Day field must be a date."

but what I am actually seeing is

"The customerBirthDate field must be a date."

I tested it in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date,ErrorMessage = "The Birth Day field must be a date.")]
[Display(Name = "Birth Day")]
public DateTime customerBirthDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Today;
```

Comment: I can't get this to work in Blazor Server 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="{0} field  is Required"]
    [DataType(DataType.Date,ErrorMessage = "{0} field must be a date.")]
    [Display(Name = "Birth Day")]
    public DateTime customerBirthDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Today;
```

You can use error message for the required attribute